# Show point labels on hover when using fviz_dend from factoextra with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I'm able to generate a plotly tree with the following:

```
library(factoextra)
library(plotly)

hcl <- hclust(
  dist(mtcars, method = "euclidean"), 
  method = "complete")

ggplotly(
  fviz_dend(
    hcl, 
    k = 5,
    show_labels = FALSE,
    type = "phylogenic",
    phylo_layout = "layout_as_tree"
  )
)
```

`fviz_dend` has an option to show labels, but this gets ugly when there are hundreds of points. Instead, I'd like to be able to hover on the point and see the labels stored in `hcl$labels`. At present, hovering only shows the coordinates and color code:

[image: See image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use the plotly package often, & hopefully someone comes along with a more elegant solution, but the following works (on my machine anyway) with phylogenic trees:

```
k = 5 # change this based on number of groups for cutting the tree

gp <- ggplotly(
  fviz_dend(
    hcl, 
    k = k,
    show_labels = TRUE, # leave this as the default TRUE, so that the labels
                        # are passed to the plotly object; we can remove them 
                        # in the next step.
    type = "phylogenic",
    phylo_layout = "layout_as_tree")
)

# remove hover text for line segments
gp$x$data[[1]]$text <- NA 

# for each group, assign the label's text value to the point's text value,
# then remove the label
for(i in seq(k, 1)){
  gp$x$data[[i+1]]$text <- gp$x$data[[i+1+k]]$text
  gp$x$data[[i + 1 + k]] <- NULL
}

gp
```

[image: screenshot]

Note: The specific number of layers created by rectangular trees appear different from the above, so the solution for phylogenic trees won't apply directly. But I assume your use case is for phylogenic ones.